# Why does my screen go completely blank when I try to use my AV cords?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

I am usually playing in HD with the HDMI cords on my Playstation 3 but right now I am at my friends house and he does not have any HD television, so I am trying to use my AV jacks but when I plug it in to the television and turn the Playstation 3 on... The screen stays dark as it was before I turned my Playstation on.

I do not know if it's my Playstation 3, my AV jacks, the television, or what but it won't show up on the screen for anything, I've tried out my friends AV jacks, it still didn't work. So It must not be the AV jacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PS3 only outputs through HDMI **or** regular AV jacks. Right now, yours is set to use HDMI. When you want to use AV jacks, ensure the PS3 is off. Then, turn it on using the button on the PS3 instead of the controller. Don't let go of the button until it beeps a second time. It will show a menu asking if you want to use HDMI or not.

Comment: So I plug in the AV cords to the TV, make sure my Playstation 3 is off, then hold the button until it beeps a second time, then I menu pops up?

Comment: Yep. You'll be able to choose which output to use.

Comment: No problem. Remember that you'll have to do the same thing when you hook it back up to your own HDTV.